# Browse and scrape web pages recursively

Tags: python, recursion, scrapy

How can I make the following crawler, using the `scrapy` python library, browse the entire website recursively:

```
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/"
    ]

def parse(self, response):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    titles = hxs.select('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li/a/text()').extract()

    for t in titles:
        print "Title: ", t
```

I've tried this on a single page:

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Society/Philosophy/Academic_Departments/Africa/"
]
```

It works well but only returns results from the start url, and doesn't follow the links within the domain.
I suppose this must be done manually with `Scrapy` but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `CrawlSpider` (see [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider)), with a single `Rule()` with a `LinkExtractor` that filters only on the domain(s) you want:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=("dmoz.org",)),
            callback='parse_page', follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li/a/text()').extract()
        for t in titles:
            print "Title: ", t
```

The callback must be called something else than `parse` (see [this warning](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules))